# jQuery success function not running in my program

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with jQuery AJAX. I successfully called the URL, but the AJAX success function is not running.

I'm use jQuery 2.0, and this my code :

What's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#simpan').click(function(){
    var data= $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url("testing/tambah") ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#message').html('<h1><sukses/h1>'); // this not running
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the actual jQuery code? This bit of code doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: `$('#message').html('<h1><sukses/h1>');`? Did you mean `$('#message').html('<h1>sukses</h1>');`? The first won't display anything in the `#message` element, so it might be working but you just can't see it.

Comment: You should look in developers tools in your browser if that ajax request is actually with 200 http code, might be that your url is not correct and your getting 4xx http codes. Or you can prog your ajax that it also report on error.

Comment: Above comments are the way forward. Another option is to specify an error callback and make sure that's not being called instead.

Comment: Use this http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/97212/ then you don't have to include your jQuery inside your PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url("testing/tambah") ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: data
}).done(function ( data ) {
    $('#message').html('<h1><sukses</h1>');
});
```